# Are pointers to virtual member functions comparable?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I read [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) saying

> A member function pointer can be set to 0, and provides the operators
>   == and !=, but only for member function pointers of the same class.

I'm trying to understand C++11, §5.10.

In **§5.10/1** it says

> Pointers of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared
>   for equality.

In **§5.10/2** it says

> Otherwise if either is a pointer to a virtual member function, the
>   result is unspecified.

Now consider the following test program.

```
#include <cassert>

class ISomeClass
{
public:
   virtual ~ISomeClass() {}

   virtual void a() = 0;
   virtual void b() = 0;
};

int main()
{
   typedef void(ISomeClass::*MemberPtr)();

   MemberPtr mp = &ISomeClass::a;

   assert( mp == &ISomeClass::a );
   assert( mp != &ISomeClass::b );

   return 0;
}
```

Are the asserts true or unspecified according to the standard?

Comment: They are “pointers of the same type”, so /1 applies, not /2 (“otherwise”).

Comment: Pointers to member are not pointers in standard parlance (see [dcl.mptr]/3). /2 applies, but there's a lot in /2 before this particular "otherwise." "If both operands are null, they compare equal. Otherwise if only one is null, they compare unequal. Otherwise if either is a pointer to a virtual member function, the result is unspecified." it says, preceded by a description of the conversions that are applied to bring the operands to the same type. It looks unspecified to me.

Comment: My English is failing me here. Does "either" mean: _any_ of the pointers, or: _not both_ of the pointers? The meaning is vital since what follows in the standard is "Otherwise they compare equal if and only if they would refer to the same member of the same most derived object", which would mean my example program would follow the standard.

Comment: I found [an article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generalizing-observer/184403873?pgno=2) by Herb Sutter saying "... because the standard directly supports pointer equality comparison for all pointer types, including all function pointer types."

Comment: In [a coding standard page](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/5-7-2-ensure-that-a-pointer-to-member-that-is-a-virtual-function-is-only-compared-with-nullptr/) they've come to the conclusion that it's **unspecified**.

Comment: A [proposal for virtual member function pointer comparison](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0191r1.pdf) has been submitted to the standardization committee.

Answer (score 1):

I think general pointer-to-member is a shift over object address. In the case of pointers to virtual methods, I think the details depends on implementation. In general case, I think is a bad idea to do that, but if pointer is solved to the correct override during asignation, it must work as a standard pointer to member function, and comparison is shift comparison plus method signature comparison. Check reinterpret_cast to long to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Please note that we're only comparing member function pointers within the same pure virtual interface. I.e. we will not compare a member function pointer from the interface with an overriding member function pointer in a subclass.

Comment: The result depends then on the compiler. It can check this expression as erroneous and reject to compile it. But if you can compile it, the comparisons must result in the expected way (assert 2 fails). imho.

Comment: Yes but that's unfortunately not portable. Not even between different versions of the same compiler.